# RavenDb and protecting the collection in a document/entity

Tags: ravendb

Hi I'm used to have the following entity

> ```
> public class Foo
> {
>     private IList<Bar> _bars;
>
>     public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }
>
>     public void Add(Bar bar)
>     {
>         /* Validation logic here */
>
>         _bars.Add(bar);
>     } 
> }
> ```

I'm suspecting this won't work with RavenDb or am I'm wrong?
Can I keep my collection with Bars protected from outside manipulating (in other words not allowing foo.Bars.Add(bar);)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to use two properties.

`public IEnumerable Bars { get { return InnerBars; } }`

private List InnerBars { get; set; }}

Comment: Yeap but json contains InnerBars not Bars, which can may introduce slight confusion, especially when consumer (other dev) doesn't see implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A private setter on an automatic property is the easiest and most readable way without doing anything special.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Bar bar)
    {
        Bars.Add(bar);
    }
}
```

Another way would be with attributes:

```cs
// pick one or the other
using Newtonsoft.Json // on 1.0
using Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json // on 2.0

...

public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Bars")]
    private IList<Bar> _bars;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get { return bars; } }

    public void Add(Bar bar)
    {
        _bars.Add(bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: First way misses ugly cast to IList when adding new bar. I like the second but I don't like attributes. That's why I'm looking forward for conventions. :)